# From any point $P$ on the line $5x+4y=20$ tangents are drawn to the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ then find the locus of the circum-centre of the $\triangle PQR$

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, circles

From any point $P$ on the line $5x+4y=20$ tangents are drawn to the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ meeting at $Q$ and $R$, then find the locus of the circum-centre of $\triangle PQR$.

My approach is as follow, if the tangent drawn from a point on the line $5x+4y=20$ to the curve meets at the point $Q$ and $R$. Then the line joining the chord of contact is $\alpha x+\beta y=4$.
As $\alpha$ and $\beta$ lies on the line $5x+4y=20$, hence $5\alpha+4\beta=20$ on comparing we get $x=1$ & $y=\frac{4}{5}$ hence the line or chord of contact is $y=mx+\frac{4}{5}-m$, I am not able to proceed from here.

Comment: have you tried using the fact that the circumcircle of $\Delta PQR $ will also pass through (0,0) and (1,$\frac{4}{5}$)

Comment: Have you attempted to use Geogebra in order to have an idea of the locus ?

Comment: To be more specific in the comment of User0, let $O$ be the origin $O=(0,0)$, and  $\Omega$ be the the circumcenter of $\Delta PQO$, which has a right angle in $Q$. Then $\Omega $ is the mid point of $PO$, and has equal distance to $P,P,Q,R$. Now we can remove the circle $x^2+y^2=4$ from the picture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @user0 and @dan_fulea mentioned in their comments above, the circumcircle of $PQR$ passes through the origin, and therefore, the circumcenter will be the midpoint of $OP$.  Therefore, if the circumcenter is $C$, then

$C = \dfrac{1}{2} P $

Since $P$ traces a line, then $C$ also traces a line.  In particular the line that $C$ traces will be parallel to the $P$ line.

Since $P$ is on the line $ 5x + 4y = 20 $, then $C$ will be on the line

$ 5 x + 4 y = 10 $

Comment: Thanking you for good explanation, this question requires understanding of geometry rather then understanding formula